$\Vert c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n\Vert_X=1$ implies coefficients must be bounded
Suppose $X$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a basis for X. Let $\Vert\cdot\Vert_X$ denote a norm on X, and $\Vert \cdot\Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ be the standard euclidean norm. Prove there exists a $B>0$ such that for all $(c_1,...,c_n)\in{\mathbb{R}^n}$ with $\Vert c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n\Vert_X=1$ we have $|c_k|\leq{B}$ for all $k=1,...,n$.
I have seen proofs for essentially the same theorem as above, but most of them use prerequisites, such as any two metrics on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent in the sense that their topologies are the same on X, or the fact that the set $\{x\in{X}:\Vert x\Vert_X=1\}$ is compact. Is there a way to prove this without these two lemmas?
My idea to prove this is to prove part of the fact that all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent, mainly that there exists an $m\in{\mathbb{R}}$ such for all $x\in{X}$ with $\Vert x\Vert_X=1$ we have $$m\Vert x\Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n}\leq{\Vert x\Vert _X}.$$ Here the left hand side metric represents the euclidean metric applied to $(c_1,...,c_n)$ where $x=\sum_{k=1}^n{c_kx_k}$. If this is true then we have $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n{c_k^2}}\leq{\frac{1}{m}}\implies{|c_k|\leq{\frac{1}{m}}}$ for all $k=1,..,n$. I have already shown that $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ defines a metric on $X$ using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, all that remains is to show the inequality above.

Define $|\sum_k c_k x_k |_c = \max_k |c_k|$. show that it is a norm.

I have shown this is a norm. How do I continue?

If it is equivalent then $\max_k |c_k| \le L | \sum_k c_k x_k|$ for some fixed $L$.

I see, but is there a way to show this without norm equivalence already given?

I believe I have found an answer for my own question. I will do this using some things I have already proven. Let $K:=\{(c_1,...,c_n)\in{\mathbb{R}^n}:\|(c_1,...,c_n)\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=1\}$. $K$ is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem. The function $f:K\to{\mathbb{R}}$ given by $$f(c_1,...,c_n):=\|c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n\|_X$$ is continuous, and thus there is a minimum, $m>0$, such that $m\leq{f(x)}$ for all $x\in{K}$. If $m=0$ then there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=0\implies{x=0}\notin{K}$, so $m>0$. We thus have for all $x\in{X}$ with $\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=1$, $\|x\|_X\geq{m}$. Now suppose $x=0$, then we have the equality $m\|0\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=\|0\|_X$. So suppose $x\neq{0}$. Then $y:=\frac{x}{\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}$ satisfies $\|y\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=1$. Thus $\|\frac{x}{\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}\|_X\geq{m}$, which gives $\|x\|_X\geq{m\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}$ for all $x\in{X}$.

Any corrections and/or feedback is much appreciated.

You use both compactness & norm equivalence here. I guess I misunderstood the question.

Sorry if it was not clear enough. I meant no use of the compactness of a closed bounded set in any finite dimensional vector space, the standard Heine-Borel theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is fine. And I proved the inequality at the end of my question. I would be fine with a proof by norm equivalence if it was proven beforehand.
